# Convert 3d pandas DataFrame to Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've got a dataframe like

```
xs = pd.DataFrame({
    'batch1': {
        'timestep1': [1, 2, 3],
        'timestep2': [3, 2, 1]
    }
}).T
```

[image: DataFrame where each cell is a list]

and I want to convert it into a numpy array of shape (batch,timestep,feature). For `xs` that should be (1,2,3).

The issue is panda only knows the 2D shape, so `to_numpy` produces a 2D shape.

```
xs.to_numpy().shape  # (1, 2)
```

Similarly, this prevents using `np.reshape` because numpy doesn't seem to see the innermost dimension as an array

```
xs.to_numpy().reshape((1,2,3))  # ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (1,2,3)
```

[Edit] Add context on how the dataframe arrived in this state.

The dataframe originally started as

```
xs = pd.DataFrame({
    ('batch1','timestep1'): {
            'feature1': 1,
            'feature2': 2,
            'feature3': 3
        },
    ('batch1', 'timestep2'): {
            'feature1': 3,
            'feature2': 2,
            'feature3': 1
        }
    }
).T
```

[image: MultiIndex dataframe]

which I decomposed into the nested list/array using

```
xs.apply(pd.DataFrame.to_numpy, axis=1).unstack()
```

[image: Unstacked dataframe]

Comment: Have you looked at what to_numpy produces?  (not just its shape)

Comment: Yep. It generally produces the correct shape, i.e. `xs.to_numpy().shape  # (1, 2)` where if you check the innermost dimension you can see the correct length: `xs.to_numpy()[0][0].shape  # (3,)`. So I'm stuck trying to promote that innermost shape up one level, I think .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

xs = pd.DataFrame({
    'batch1': {
        'timestep1': [1, 2, 3],
        'timestep2': [3, 2, 1]
    }
}).T

xs = pd.concat((xs.explode('timestep1').drop('timestep2', axis=1), xs.explode('timestep2').drop('timestep1', axis=1)), axis=1)
print(xs, '\n')

n = xs.to_numpy().reshape(1, 2, 3)
print(n)
```

Output:

```
       timestep1 timestep2
batch1         1         3
batch1         2         2
batch1         3         1 

[[[1 3 2]
  [2 3 1]]]
```

#### EDIT

Starting from your original data frame you can do:

```
xs = pd.DataFrame({
    ('batch1','timestep1'): {
            'feature1': 1,
            'feature2': 2,
            'feature3': 3
        },
    ('batch1', 'timestep2'): {
            'feature1': 3,
            'feature2': 2,
            'feature3': 1
        },
    ('batch2','timestep1'): {
            'feature1': 4,
            'feature2': 5,
            'feature3': 6
        },
    ('batch2', 'timestep2'): {
            'feature1': 7,
            'feature2': 8,
            'feature3': 9
        }
    }
).T


array = xs.to_numpy().reshape(2,2,3)
print(array)
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [3 2 1]]

 [[4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]]
```

Comment: Could the explode/drop be avoided if the DataFrame started as a multiindex? i.e. (batch, timestep) = [feature]

Comment: Could you show how you would transform your data frame in such a MultiIndex?

Comment: Sure. Edited the question description.

Comment: See the Edit in the post.

Comment: Thanks! The issue was my original dataframe was jagged. One I leveled all the timesteps I was able to `to_numpy().reshape` as expected.